# Finding punctuation within VBA string from the right side

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA, how do I find the first instance of a punctuation symbol, from the right hand side? For example, from "!", I should be able to get the term "Security" two times in the following string:

```
INDEX(Security![a range], MATCH(J2,Security![a range],0))
```

Something like InStrRev would be ideal but seems like it doesnt support regex expressions. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's true that `InStrRev()` doesn't accept `RegEx` patterns, but VBA does support `RegEx` and there would be a way of achieving what you need with it. However, just looping through each character and looking for any punctuation mark is pretty straightforward and might be a route you prefer.

Skeleton code (with only a few punctuation marks) below:

```
Public Sub RunMe()
    Const punc As String = "!""*()-[]{};':@~,./<>?"

    Debug.Print InStrRevAny("T:E'S!T", punc)
End Sub
Private Function InStrRevAny(refText As String, chars As String) As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    For i = Len(refText) To 1 Step -1
        For j = 1 To Len(chars)
            If Mid(refText, i, 1) = Mid(chars, j, 1) Then
                InStrRevAny = i
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Function
```