# How can I create a range which excludes punctuation in Microsoft Word VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to turn the first few letters of every word bold.

This is meant to format a document for bionic reading (which hasn't been proven but I want to try it out anyway).

My code turns the first few letters of a word bold. However, it also highlights punctuation and thinks full stops and commas etc. are words. I want the range to ignore punctuation.

Current code:

```vb
Sub BionicReading()
    Dim objWord As Range
        
    ' Cycle through each word in an open document.
    For Each objWord In ActiveDocument.Words
    
        ' Set Bold for the first letter in every word.
        objWord.Characters(1).Font.Bold = True
        
        If objWord.Characters.Count > 3 Then
        
            Dim L As Integer
            L = Round((objWord.Characters.Count - 1) / 2)
            Dim i As Integer
        
            ' Cycle through half the characters in each word
            For i = 2 To L
                ' Set character bold.
                objWord.Characters(i).Font.Bold = True
            Next i
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I tried an if statement (simplified to a few punctuation marks) as the first line in the first For loop:

```vb
If objWord = "." Or objWord = "," Or objWord = "-" Then
Else
```

I think it sees punctuation followed by other punctuation as one word or maybe spaces after punctuation as one word. If this is the case it would require too many Or statements to be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `InStrRev` function worked a treat. The complete code is below if anybody wants to try it out. The function also classifies the space after a word as a character so I had to add a few more lines to get my desired number of characters highlighted.

```
Sub BionicReading()

    Dim objWord As Range
    Const punc As String = "!""^&*()-{}[]:;'@#~/?<>,.\1234567890"
    
    For Each objWord In ActiveDocument.Words
        If InStrRev(punc, objWord.Characters(1), , 1) > 0 Then
        Else
            objWord.Characters(1).Font.Bold = True
        
            Dim L As Integer
            L = objWord.Characters.Count
        
            If objWord.Characters(L) = " " Then
                If L > 4 Then

                    Dim x As Integer
                    Dim L2 As Integer
                    L2 = Round((L - 2) / 2)

                    For x = 2 To L2
                        objWord.Characters(x).Font.Bold = True
                    Next x
                End If
            Else
                If L > 3 Then

                    Dim y As Integer
                    Dim L3 As Integer
                    L3 = Round((L - 1) / 2)

                    For y = 2 To L3
                        objWord.Characters(y).Font.Bold = True
                    Next y
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that punctuation is considered a word by the .Words method. Individual punctuations are counted as a word, and groups of punctuation are also considered as single words.

Try changing your if statement to check only the first character of the word. It may also help if you use a punctuation string or array for comparison instead of chaining if statements.

A function like this answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41679626/17927534

Comment: This works, thank you! I have posted the complete code below in case anybody wants to test it out.